# QML Can't capture keyboard event

Tags: keyboard, focus, qml, listviewitem

I have a page where I am showing three Items. When the page is first time opened I show Item # 1 (the other two are visible = false). I can catch keyboard events in the items Keys.onPressed event. Then on some specific selection I show Item # 2 and hide Item # 1 , Item # 3. (i.e Item # 2 contains a dynamically loaded ListView). I can catch keyboard events in this item as well in my Keys.onPressed event. Based on some user selection I show Item # 3, and hide Item # 2, Item # 1 (again with visible = false). The Item # 3 is being show properly, but I can not catch Keys.onPressed event of this item despite the fact that I have got the focus (which I have tested with QML debugging). I even can't catch the Keys.onPressed of any item on this page (shown or not shown - not even where I was catching this event before showing Item # 3).

This problem only appears if I open Item # 3 after Item # 2, and the only special thing in Item # 2 is dynamically created ListView.

Following is my code, I have tried to put enough comments here.

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Item {
    id: wifilist_screen
    width: 1920;
    height: 1080;

    Connections {
        target: guiStrings;
        onApsPageReadyToOpen: {
            hideEnableDisableScreen();
            showApsListScreen();
        }
    }
    Connections {
        target: guiStrings;
        onOpenWifiAuthenticationPage: {
            hideApsListScreen();
            showWifiAuthenticationPage();
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: listScreen;
        width: parent.width;
        height: parent.height;
        color: "black";

        // ============== Wifi Authentication Screen
        // This item is being shown with following two functions. 
        // hideApsListScreen, showWifiAuthenticationPage. The problem is
        // I can't input from the keyboard when this page is shown. I have
        // did QML debugging and wifiAuthScreen does have activeFocus = true
        // and authTypeOption.focus to true but when I press key from the
        // keyboard I am expecting it to be catched by Keys.onPressed, but 
        // I don't. Even I am not catching key events by any Keys.onPressed
        // handler mentioned on this page or even its previous page. 
        // I see this problem only when I open this screen after list_view 
        // screen (i.e The screen which contains a dynamic List model.
        Item {
            id: wifiAuthScreen;
            visible: false;
            focus: false;

            // Show Function Menu Options Options
            MenuOption {
                id: authTypeOption;
                y: header.height + 50;
                x: 200;
                text: guiStrings.txtSecurity;
                expandableOption: true;
                selected: true;
                inside: true;
                selection: guiStrings.txtNone;
                selection_disabled: true;
                Keys.onPressed: handleKeyEvent(event);
            }
        }
        // ============== Enable / Disable Screen
        // NOTE: This is the first item shown on the page when 
        // we open the page. It shows a menu with two options
        // Enable / Disable. Pressing Enable will cause C++
        // code to throw signal onApsPageReadyToOpen()
        // and then I catch that signal and call the function
        // hideEnableDisableScreen: I hide this item
        // showApsListScreen : I show following item.
        Item {
            id: enableDisableScreen;
            visible: true;
            focus: true;
            MenuOption {
                id: enableOption;
                y: header.height;
                text: guiStrings.txtOn;
                expandableOption: false;
                selection: "";
                selected: true;
            }
            Keys.onPressed: handleKeyEvent(event); <-- Working great.
        }
        // ========== Wifi Access Points List Screen
        // This shows a dynamic List model. Once I select some index item
        // from the list on pressing Return I call a C++ code and that 
        // throws a signal onOpenWifiAuthenticationPage(). 
        // Here I catch onOpenWifiAuthenticationPage and hide this page, 
        // and show page having the id: wifiAuthScreen. 
        Component {
            id: listDelegate
            MenuOption {
                id: wifiOption;
                text: ssid;
                expandableOption: false;
                selection: "";
                selected: if ( index == list_view.currentIndex ) true; else false;
                Keys.onPressed: {
                    handleKeyEvent(event); <-- Working Great.
                }
            }
        }
        ListView {
            id: list_view
            width:      parent.width;
            height:     1080 - header.height;
            y: header.height;
            currentIndex: 0;
            boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
            model: wifiNetworksModel;
            delegate: listDelegate;
            visible: false;
        }
    }
    function handleKeyEvent(event)
    {
        // --------------------------------------
        // We are showing Wifi Enable / Disable screen
        // --------------------------------------
        if ( enableDisableScreen.visible ) {
            if ( event.key == Qt.Key_Up || event.key == Qt.Key_Down ) {
                if ( enableOption.selected ) {
                    enableOption.selected = false;
                    disableOption.selected = true;
                } else if ( disableOption.selected ) {
                    disableOption.selected = false;
                    enableOption.selected = true;
                }
            } else if ( event.key == Qt.Key_Return ) {
                if ( enableOption.selected ) {
                    guiStrings.EnableDisableWifi(true);
                } else if ( disableOption.selected ) {
                    wifiIsDisabled(true);
                }
            } else if ( event.key == Qt.Key_Left ) {
                wifiIsDisabled(false);
            }
        }
        // --------------------------------------
        // We are showing Wifi Access Points List screen
        // --------------------------------------
        else if ( list_view.visible ) {
            if ( event.key == Qt.Key_Up ) {
                if ( list_view.currentIndex == 0 )
                    list_view.currentIndex = (list_view.count);
            } else if ( event.key == Qt.Key_Down ) {
                if ( list_view.currentIndex == (list_view.count - 1))
                    list_view.currentIndex = -1;
            } else if ( event.key == Qt.Key_Left ) {
                event.accepted = true;
                hideApsListScreen();
                showEnableDisableScreen();
            } else if ( event.key == Qt.Key_Return ) {
                event.accepted = true;
                hideApsListScreen();
                guiStrings.ActivateWifiConnection(list_view.currentIndex);
            }
        }
        // --------------------------------------
        // We are showing wifi authentication screen
        // --------------------------------------
        else if ( wifiAuthScreen.visible ) {

        }
    }
    function showEnableDisableScreen() {
        enableDisableScreen.visible = true;
        enableDisableScreen.focus = true;
        enableOption.selected = true;
        disableOption.selected = false;
    }
    function hideEnableDisableScreen() {
        enableDisableScreen.visible = false;
        enableDisableScreen.focus = false;
    }
    function showApsListScreen() {
        list_view.focus = true;
        list_view.visible = true;
        list_view.currentIndex = 0;
    }
    function hideApsListScreen() {
        list_view.focus = false;
        list_view.visible = false;
    }
    function showWifiAuthenticationPage() {
        wifiAuthScreen.forceActiveFocus();
        wifiAuthScreen.focus = true;
        wifiAuthScreen.visible = true;
        authTypeOption.focus = true;
        currentAuthType = "none";
    }
    function hideWifiAuthenticationPage() {
        wifiAuthScreen.focus = false;
        wifiAuthScreen.visible = false;
    }
}
```

In summary, the problem it seems the keyboard events are being lost somewhere. I have valid focus on my Item where I want to capture events, I even't cant capture the events on the main page of my application. This problem only occurs if I open problematic item after the item which contains a ListView with dynamic model.

Any help is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Farrukh Arshad.

Comment: One note first: in QML1, focus is broken (but ok in QMl2), beware.